# Relaxing MIME type checking in Android's WebView? Or forcing module type for regular javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing and app in Android which has a piece written in javascript and python using [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) (it'd almost be the same as saying that I am developing that part straight in javascript, but I do not have full control on how things are made). Android displays that section in an Activity with a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView). The relevant java code to start it is simply

```
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/AndroidWebView.html");
```

and the relevant part of `AndroidWebView.html` is similar to [Transcript's demo for iOS](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/blob/master/transcrypt/demos/ios_app/ios_app.html)

```
        <script type="module">
            import * as my_app from "./target/my_app.js"; window.my_app = my_app;
        </script>
```

The app works just fine on the emulator, but on real devices WebView refuses to load the javascript and spits out the following error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

If I force the MIME type by changing the HTML to

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            import * as my_app from "./target/my_app.js"; window.my_app = my_app;
        </script>
```

which seems to work for other parts of my page that are plain javascript (not modules), it obviously fail with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

**Is there a way to either force the latter HTML to be a module, or the former HTML to not check the MIME types so strongly?**

Looking at the [options for WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings) I could not see anything that seems relevant. Looking around, this issue seems to be caused exactly by [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=824651).

On the other hand, it seems to me that the problem is the syntax of the HTML `script` tag of accepting type to be either `"text/javascript"` or `"module"` but not both at the same time (I tried and it seems to use only the first), whereas semantically there are reasons to have both. Is there are workaround, or even a hack to have both? I know one hack that would work for loading the `my_app.js`, but that one would fail to further load other modules (which `my_app.js` does). So that won't work unless there is a transpiler or something able to automatically merge all my modules into one. FWIW, those modules are generated from python from Transcrypt, so it must be an automated, not manual process.

PS: I am not HTML or javascript developer, these are my first steps in this realm, so please be kind against my speculations

PPS: I understand the reason for not doing any of this on a computer, but rather start up a server. And that is what I do for my development environment. But for one single Activity in an Android App, an HTTP server seems an overkill and a big headache (tracking ports, potential more failure modes, potentially visible in the browser or in other apps, additional permissions, additional resources and battery usage, and probably more troubles that I have not thought about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things you could try.

1.
Make sure it is html 5 by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to your index.html

2.
Instead of loading the file directly from the system using file://... you can use the WebViewAssetLoader this will return the mimetype
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader

3.
If that does not work inside the webViewClient you could intercept the request and add the text/javascript mimetype manually:

```
val webViewAssetLoader = WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
        .addPathHandler("/assets/", WebViewAssetLoader.AssetsPathHandler(context!!))
        .build()

val webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
        val interceptedWebRequest = webViewAssetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.url)
        interceptedWebRequest?.let {
            if (request.url.toString().endsWith("js", true)) {
                it.mimeType = "text/javascript"
            }
        }
        return interceptedWebRequest
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I already have that. 2. & 3. If my understanding is correct, I need to use AndroidX for WebViewAssetLoader. If again my understanding is correct, that consequently means that I have to target API level 28, or less than 1% of the devices. In other words, it would not work. PS: I am upvoting your answer anyway because I was not aware of this option, and it may turn useful in the future, but not accepting it because it is useless to me now  (unless I'm wrong with my understanding mentioned above, please correct me if that's the case)

Comment: AndroidX does not require you to target (minSdkVersion) API level 28 or higher. Androidx replaces old support libraries. AndroidX requires MinSdkVersion of at least 14. Check out https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate to migrate your project to AndroidX.

Comment: Here is a good explenation of the differences between compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.bpqsg4ili.

Comment: thanks and yes, I know that documentation for migrating which you linked (sadly it is extremely poor and it fails to migrate my project, but that is a secondary problem which I can solve is I try hard enough). Instead the problem is that I started a new project and could not use WebViewAssetLoader anyway even in API 27. Too long to discuss in a comment, please see my new question about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722739/

Comment: 2. alone did not work (same error), but 3. fixed it (once I solved the "import androidx.webkit" problem as described in the other question). Accepting the answer.

Comment: @Davide I do not have enought reputation to comment on your java solution but shouldInterceptRequest could potentially return null. So you might want to check for that before setting the mimeType.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I've edited the response accordingly

Answer (score 5):

I am just restating the previous answer in an easier to read way (and with Java instead of Kotlin)

1. Not sure it matters, but it's best practice to use html 5 by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. `import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader;` as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722739/)
3. force the correct MIME type with something like

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                WebResourceResponse intercepted = assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
                if (request.getUrl().toString().endsWith("js")) {
                        if (intercepted != null) {
                            intercepted.setMimeType("text/javascript");
                        }
                }
                return intercepted;
            }
        });
```

4. load the HTML with something like

```
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/AndroidWebView.html");
```

Note the HTTPS (not file) protocol, and the absence of `AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs`

Comment: What is assetLoader? Trying to add `WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader().Builder().build();` doesn't work. No problem with `import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader;`.

Comment: WebViewAssetLoader is not public.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add, it is better to use `request.getUrl().getPath().endsWith(".js")` because the URL may contain query parameters, in that case it won't end with .js