# How to find which API level an Android class has been introduced?

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I created a new Android project, targeting API 15 and using `androidx`. The autogenerated `Hello world` is:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Adding `import androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader` to it fails with `Cannot resolve symbol webkit`.

So I tried to create another project, this time targeting API level 27, with the same result, and I concluded that the API I needed was 28 (and gave up because I do not want to target something so restricting). Someone commenting on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588170/relaxing-mime-type-checking-in-androids-webview-or-forcing-module-type-for-reg/) suggested that is not the case, hence this question, which is twofold.

1. Where can one find which API level a particular class targets? The [documentation on WebViewAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) does not say.
2. Am I missing something in my project, e.g. additional JARs which are optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> and I concluded that the API I needed was 28

That's not really what's going on here.

You are trying to import `androidx.webkit.WebViewAssetLoader`. The first segment of that package is `androidx`. Every `androidx` class comes from a library. You simply don't have that library, apparently.

In an ideal world, you would be able to visit [the official JavaDocs for that class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) and be told which Jetpack library contains it. This is not an ideal world.

So, that's why I go through the trouble of maintaining [AndroidX Tech](https://androidx.tech/), to fill in some of these documentation gaps. If you choose "W*" in the "Classes" drop-down, you will find [`WebViewAssetLoader` is part of the `androidx.webkit:webkit` library](https://androidx.tech/packages/androidx.webkit#WebViewAssetLoader), version `1.1.0` or higher.

Right now (2020-03-17), `1.2.0` is the most recent version, so add:

```
implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.2.0"
```

to your `dependencies` in your module's `build.gradle`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wow, who could have imagined such a thing? Looks like a mess.... Thanks for maintaining such a website!

Comment: +1 "This is not the ideal world". Coming from .net, where most things are a nuget search away, it's been a rough ride so far with the Java(tm) way of doing things.